# Ability to have a decimal fontSize value in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I wonder why i can't seem to be able to apply a decimal value to fontSize in Flex. I have tryid it with flash textfield component, mx label and text but nothing seems to accept a decimal value. fontSize is accepting Number and i can set a decimal value to fonts in Flash so i can't see why this isn't working in Flex?

Is there anny solutions to this problem?

Comment: It does not accept decimal. However, you may try setting it in a style sheet. I have not tried this but it may work.

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use scaleX and scaleY.

```
<mx:Label text="Label" fontSize="24" scaleX=".9" scaleY=".9" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I later figured out that you are able to specify a decimal value to font size when using TLF based textfields like most spark component does.